# Combining two arrays with for loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, numbers

```
var number = [1,2,3,4];
var assignment= ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"];
```

I need to combine these two arrays so that it console logs this information like so:

```
1 first
2 second
3 third
4 fourth
```

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried any code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine them like

```js
var number = [1,2,3,4]; var assignment= ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"];
// alert (number[i] + " = " + assignment[number[i]-1]);
// change "i" as desired
alert (number[0] + " = " + assignment[number[0]-1]);
```

Now you can loop and combine them like this,

```js
var number = [1,2,3,4]; var assignment= ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"];
for(var i=0;i<4;i++)
{
  alert (number[i] + " = " + assignment[number[i]-1]);
}
```

I you want a string, you can do something like this,

```js
var number = [1,2,3,4]; var assignment= ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"];
var txt = "";
for(var i=0;i<4;i++)
{
  txt = txt + (number[i] + " = " + assignment[number[i]-1] + " ");
}
alert(txt);
```

Comment: Nice one, with more than one example, that's a yes yes :)

Answer (score 0):

If the arrays has the same leght, it should do the work

```
var number = [1,2,3,4];
var assignment= ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"];
var result = new Array(number.length)
for(var i=0;i<number.length;i++){
    result[i] = (number[i] + " " + assignment[i]);
}
```

then you can print them

Answer (score 0):

The following will work as long as the arrays are equal in size:

```js
var number = [1,2,3,4];
var assignment = ["one","two","three","four"];
var size = number.count;
for(var i=0; i<size; i++){
    var log = number[i] + " " + assignment[i];
    console.log(log);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `forEach`:

```js
var arr = [];
var number = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var assignment = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"];
var i = 0;
number.forEach(function(e) {
  arr.push(e + ' ' + assignment[i++])
});
console.info(arr)
```

> **WARNING**: We assume the arrays size are equal